# convert c# datatype to equivalent java datatype

Tags: c#, java

I have few datatypes used in C# that I need to translate to Java.

`uint`, `Int16`, `UInt16`, `Nullable<Int16>`

What will be the appropriate datatype for these in Java?

Answer (score 6):

Although the link provided by x2 is good, it's not all that useful when dealing with unsigned primitives. For example: the range of an int is 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (which is the same in both languages), but the range of C#s uint is 0 to 4,294,967,295.  Java doesn't have a similar primitive type, so you'd have to use something that contains that range (in this case, a long).

If you are only worried about 1-way compatibility (C# to Java) these should work:

- **c# --> java**
- uint --> long
- Int16 --> short
- UInt16 --> short
- Nullable --> look into the classes that wrap the primitive types (i.e. Integer wraps an int)

EDIT::
I just found [this article on MSDN about the differences between the data types in the two languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Data type equivalents between Java and C#.  Hope you can find it out.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Chek it out](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/java_csharp_comparison.html)

Comment: Link has rotten. Please don't give link-only answers. It's always better to give full or short answer with a link to a source.